# How to make user-controls in Godot automatically show their children inside an intenal container of my choice?

Tags: godot, godot4

Consider a control that behaves as a decorator to user provided controls, like a window frame. I want my control to have all the common logic of the window (title bar, draggable window borders, buttons to hide the window, etc) and any time it's instanced in the main scene I want it to "eat" any of its node children and place them into a container of my choice.

This is the control I made, and the `LinesContainer` container is where I want any of its children to reside:

[image: Control Tree] [image: Control Visual]

And just to be absolutely clear what I mean, when it's instantiated into a scene as below, I want its children (the label, in this case) to behave as if they were children of the `LinesContainer` node instead:

[image]

If you are familiar with .Net XAML at all, this is what the `ContentPresenter` tag does in a control, it "eats" the `Content` property of the entire control (ie, the children of the control instance, as above) and displays it inside that tag, allowing me to create anything I need around it (or behind it, or over it, etc).

Is there anything built-in like `ContentPresenter`? Or if not, how would I go about making something of my own? If possible, that also works correctly in the editor, allowing me to add and remove items as I need and have them layout correctly.

Comment: Note that work-arounds are far less interesting to me, as I can achieve what I want by copy-pasting the frame around the window and its code in all of my windows myself. What I want is an automatic way to "decorate" nodes with my own user-defined controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my best attempt to do what you ask for, as written. I have done some testing in Godot 4.1 and 4.2.dev 2, and it works with some caveats I'll get into.

But before I get into that, I want to mention that using base `Container` is not recommendable as it is a `Container` that does nothing. Thus you might instead use a regular `Control`. And yes, the solution I present can be modified to work with a regular `Control`, I'll get to that at the end.

**Addendum**: I guess the Godot standard approach would have been to use "Editable Children" (which you find in the context menu of the scene instance in the Scene dock), I want to mention it, just in case you are not aware of that. Also, the feature you want could make for a good proposal: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues (at least consider opening a discussion: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/discussions)

Design considerations and caveats:

- Since you say this is like a `ContentPresenter` from XAML, I'm calling the new class `ContentPresenter`.
- I do not want to remove the children `Control`s nor reparent them, as this might result in problems (e.g. a `NodePath` no longer being correct, or the script on the control not handling being removed from the scene tree).
- I do not require to add code to the children `Control`s. This is all in the new `ContentPresenter` class.
- Perhaps you intent to hardcode where the `Container` is, however I'm handling the case where the `Container` might change, under the idea that it would be easier for you to remove that part of my code than to add it. And perhaps you learn something in the process.
- Since this must work in the editor, we will have a `@tool` script.
- Given that I want a `@tool` script to have a variable reference to another node... I will not expose a `Container` property, but a `NodePath` property (I got a crash trying to use the `Container` property while developing this in Godot 4.2.dev5 - whatever it was I hope will be fixed for the stable release - but I'm falling back to the old way for this).
- Since Containers are designed to operate on their children (setting their position and size), and which kind of `Container` you will use is not clear, I want to have something actually as child of the `Container`.
- Thus, I must create - what I'll call - `dual`s of the children on the `Container`, and copy their position properties back and forth.
- You won't see the `dual`s in the scene tree. This is because they do not have an `owner`, and consequently won't be stored with the scene either. Instead they will be regenerated when the scene loads (either in the editor or in runtime).
- I'm mapping `dual`s to the children `Control`s using metadata, which I temporarily compile into a `Dictionary`. Before I was storing the `Dictionary` but ran into issues of it getting out sync. I also did consider using `name`s, but that might have caused a conflict if you wanted to have children of the `Container` already there (e.g. `Cursor`).
- Speaking of children of the `Container` already there, the code will place the `dual`s *after* them (if you want them before, replace the computation of `children_to_skip` with `0`).
- I'm using the signals `child_entered_tree`, `child_order_changed` and `child_order_changed` to make sure the correct duals exists in the correct order. And the signals `minimum_size_changed` and `item_rect_changed` to trigger the copy of the position properties. Here `item_rect_changed` seems to make `resized` redundant, and I didn't find another way to handle the change of position (other than checking each frame, which would be much less efficient).
- Speaking of checking each frame, I didn't find a way to get a signal when the resize flags changed, so to detect if they changed I would have to check every frame (in `_process`) however, I'm not including that in this answer (The code will keep `_process` disable most of the time to reduce performance impact). As a result changes in size flags won't be reflected right away, you can take advantage of the `dual`s being regenerated to fix it in the editor, calling `_invalidate_childdren` should fix it too.
- This does not solve Z-ordering. If you want something to be on top of the child `Control`s, placing it onto of top of the `Container`s won't do.
- I had to figure out how to get the position properties in global coordinates to copy them around correctly.

This is the code:

```
@tool
class_name ContentPresenter
extends Control

# Reference to the container that children will behave as if they were in
var target_container:Container
# NodePath to the container that children will behave as if they were in
@export var target_container_path:NodePath:
    set(mod_value):
        # Update the NodePath
        target_container_path = mod_value
        # Update the reference et.al. only if this node is ready
        # If this node is not ready, the reponsability falls to _ready
        if is_node_ready():
            _update_target_container()


var invalidated_children:bool:
    set(mod_value):
        if invalidated_children == mod_value:
            return

        invalidated_children = mod_value


var invalidated_container:bool:
    set(mod_value):
        if invalidated_container == mod_value:
            return

        invalidated_container = mod_value


func _invalidate_children() -> void:
    invalidated_children = true
    set_process(true)


func _invalidate_container() -> void:
    invalidated_container = true
    set_process(true)


# Runs when this node is ready
func _ready() -> void:
    # Make sure child_entered_tree is connected
    if not child_entered_tree.is_connected(_child_entered_tree):
        child_entered_tree.connect(_child_entered_tree)

    # Make sure child_exiting_tree is connected
    if not child_exiting_tree.is_connected(_child_exiting_tree):
        child_exiting_tree.connect(_child_exiting_tree)

    # Make sure child_order_changed is connected
    if not child_order_changed.is_connected(_child_order_changed):
        child_order_changed.connect(_child_order_changed)

    # Update the container reference if necessary
    _update_target_container()
    _invalidate_children()


# Runs when this node leaves the scene tree
func _exit_tree() -> void:
    # Request to run _ready next time it enters the scene tree
    # This is so it can update the reference to the container
    request_ready()


# Called by the Godot edito to get warning
func _get_configuration_warnings() -> PackedStringArray:
    # If we don't have a valid reference to the container put up a warning
    if not is_instance_valid(target_container):
        return ["Target Container Not Found"]
    
    return []


func _process(_delta: float) -> void:
    if is_instance_valid(target_container):
        var control_by_dual := {}
        var dual_by_control := {}
        var duals_to_remove:Array[Control] = []
        var children_to_skip := 0
        for dual_candidate in target_container.get_children():
            if dual_candidate.has_meta("__dual_of"):
                var control := _validate_control(dual_candidate.get_meta("__dual_of", null))
                if is_instance_valid(control):
                    control_by_dual[dual_candidate] = control
                    dual_by_control[control] = dual_candidate
                else:
                    duals_to_remove.append(dual_candidate)
            else:
                children_to_skip += 1

        if invalidated_container:
            for dual in control_by_dual.keys():
                var control:Control = control_by_dual[dual]
                _copy_positioning(dual, control, false)

        if invalidated_children:
            # Make sure all the children Controls have a dual, and what should their order be
            var order:Array[Control] = []
            for control_candidate in get_children():
                var control := _validate_control(control_candidate)
                if not is_instance_valid(control):
                    continue

                var dual:Control = dual_by_control.get(control, null)
                if not is_instance_valid(dual):
                    dual = Control.new()
                    # When the child control changes its minimum size, update the dual
                    if not control.minimum_size_changed.is_connected(_invalidate_children):
                        control.minimum_size_changed.connect(_invalidate_children)

                    # When the child control moves or resizes, update the dual
                    if not control.item_rect_changed.is_connected(_invalidate_children):
                        control.item_rect_changed.connect(_invalidate_children)

                    # When the dual moves or resizes, update the child control
                    if not dual.item_rect_changed.is_connected(_invalidate_container):
                        dual.item_rect_changed.connect(_invalidate_container)

                    dual.set_meta("__dual_of", control)
                    control_by_dual[dual] = control
                    dual_by_control[control] = dual
                    target_container.add_child(dual)
                    #dual.owner = owner if owner != null else self

                order.append(dual)

            # Remove any duals whose child Control is no longer valid
            for dual in duals_to_remove:
                target_container.remove_child(dual)
                dual.queue_free()

            # Clear the list to remove so we don't remove them again
            duals_to_remove = []

            # Make sure the dual is in the correct order in the container children
            for index in order.size():
                target_container.move_child(order[index], children_to_skip + index)

            # Update the duals position
            for dual in control_by_dual.keys():
                var control = control_by_dual[dual]
                _copy_positioning(control, dual, true)

        # Remove any duals whose child Control is no longer valid (if they weren't removed before)
        for dual in duals_to_remove:
            target_container.remove_child(dual)
            dual.queue_free()

    set_process(false)


# Called by _ready or target_container_path's setter
func _update_target_container():
    # Figure out the new reference to the container
    var new_target_container:Container = null
    if not target_container_path.is_empty():
        new_target_container = get_node_or_null(target_container_path)

    # If it is the same reference do nothing
    if new_target_container == target_container:
        update_configuration_warnings()
        return

    # Since we are going to change container, remove duals from the old one
    if is_instance_valid(target_container):
        var children := target_container.get_children()
        for child in children:
            if child.has_meta("__dual_of"):
                target_container.remove_child(child)

        if target_container.item_rect_changed.is_connected(_invalidate_container):
            target_container.item_rect_changed.disconnect(_invalidate_container)

    # Update the container reference
    target_container = new_target_container
    if is_instance_valid(target_container):
        if not target_container.item_rect_changed.is_connected(_invalidate_container):
            target_container.item_rect_changed.connect(_invalidate_container)

    _invalidate_container()
    _invalidate_children()
    # Tell Godot to update warning
    update_configuration_warnings()


# Handler for child_entered_tree
func _child_entered_tree(node:Node) -> void:
    var control := _validate_control(node)
    if control == null:
        return

    _invalidate_children()


# Handler for child_exiting_tree
func _child_exiting_tree(node:Node) -> void:
    var control := _validate_control(node)
    if control == null:
        return

    _invalidate_children()


# Handler for child_order_changed
func _child_order_changed() -> void:
    _invalidate_children()


# Called from _child_entered_tree and _child_exiting_tree
func _validate_control(node:Node) -> Control:
    if node.owner == self:
        # We got a node that is part of the scene
        return null

    var control = node as Control
    if not is_instance_valid(control):
        # We got a node that is not a Control
        return null

    if control.get_parent() != self:
        return null

    if (
        is_instance_valid(target_container)
        and (
            control == target_container
            or control.is_ancestor_of(target_container)
        )
    ):
        # We got a Control that contains the container
        return null

    # return the Control
    return control


# Copies data between the children Controls and their duals
func _copy_positioning(from:Control, to:Control, is_push:bool) -> void:
    # global transform of from
    var from_global_transform := from.get_global_transform()
    
    # global transform of the parent of to
    var to_parent_global_transform := Transform2D.IDENTITY
    var to_parent := to.get_parent_control()
    if to_parent != null:
        to_parent_global_transform = to_parent.get_global_transform()

    # transform of from relative to the parent of to
    var from_to_local_transform := to_parent_global_transform.affine_inverse() * from_global_transform

    if is_push:
        to.visible = from.visible
        to.size_flags_horizontal = from.size_flags_horizontal
        to.size_flags_vertical = from.size_flags_vertical
        to.size_flags_stretch_ratio = from.size_flags_stretch_ratio
        to.custom_minimum_size = from.get_combined_minimum_size()

    to.size = from.size
    to.global_position = from_global_transform.origin
    to.rotation = from_to_local_transform.get_rotation()
    to.scale = from_to_local_transform.get_scale()
```

As you can see I have added some comments, which I hope help understand what is going on.

However, I want to elaborate further on a few things:

- You will see that I check `is_node_ready` before updating the reference to the `Container` that is because I want to make sure that this node is in the scene tree before trying to access it (to query the `NodePath`). If the node is not ready, then `_ready` will call the method to update the reference. If the node is removed from the scene tree (perhaps the `NodePath` modified while it is not in the scene tree) and added again, I'd need to update the reference again, for that I use `request_ready` to make sure `_ready` runs again (otherwise `_ready` would only run the first time).
- The method `_validate_control` checks if the `ContentPresenter` is the owner, which would be the case for `Node`s added in the editor in a scene where the `ContentPresenter` is the root. So this makes it easy to skip those `Node`s. It also checks if the `Control` is actually a child of the `ContentPresenter`, allowing to detect if a `dual` is pointing to a removed `Control` that is otherwise still a valid instance.
- The method `_copy_positioning` is really the heart of this (and what took more time to figure out). It might be useful to you if you even do not need all the extra setup. I'll get to that.
- The `_process` method will disable itself with `set_process(false)` and calling `_invalidate_children` or `_invalidate_container` enables it again.
- The method `_get_configuration_warnings` will be called by Godot to
  get, well, warnings. They show up as that yellow triangle next to the `Node` in the scene tree.
- I'll reiterate that this does not fix Z-Order.

---

Now, if you do not need the target to ge a `Container`, you only need to change it in a a couple places:

1. `var target_container:Container`
2. `var new_target_container:Container = null`

Plus it is also mentioned in the `_get_configuration_warnings`, and names of variables and methods, but these are not functional.

You could also remove the line where `dual.item_rect_changed` is connected if the target is not a `Container`, under the assumption that only `Container`s would be moving or resizing their children.

---

I also want to note that handling this as a transformation would have been problematic. It would be an infinite feedback loop:

- Get the position of the `Control`.
- Transform it.
- Update the position of the `Control`.
- The position of the `Control` changed, repeat.

Thus I would have needed to keep track of the original values, and in a way that would still let you edit them. Thus, I believe the `dual`s is a good solution.

---

I had initially posted this answer without using `_process`, but I ran into order of execution problems from the signals. Which are important: Say both the `Container` and a child `Control` moved, which one updates from the other first matters.

Now using `_process` I'm giving preference to the `Container` moving the child `Control`, which minimizes the situations where they behave incorrectly.

---

Perhaps you actually do not need to handle multiple children. Instead you might want to just copy the positioning of one `Control` (e.g. the `Container`) to another `Control` (e.g. what you are placing "inside" the `Container`). In which case the method `_copy_positioning` might still be useful to you... But you can get rid of all the `dual`s et.al.

Thus, I submit to your consideration specifying what you will put inside the `Container` using a `NodePath`.

*No, copying the `Container` position to the `ContentPresenter` won't work, if you want the `ContentPresenter` to be a parent of the `Container`. But there might be an alternative approach hiding in there if you are OK not having the `Container` as a child of the `ContentPresenter`. For example, it could be similar to `RemoteTransform`(`2D`/`3D`) but for `Control`s. But anyway, that is not the question as written.*

Comment: Somehow it didn't occur to me to make this class a Container (after all it moves and resizes it's children), which might had allowed me to take advantage of of features of Containers - I do not know if I would had run into different issues. Anyway, this works, and I need my time.

Comment: Man, you put a lot of work into this. I guess my problem with this approach is the need to create these duals, thus doubling the weight of individual controls. Does everyone do this when they create popups in games? It seems insane to me that the best other solution is "just copy & paste the window frame everywhere"...

Comment: @Blindy If you enable "Editable Children" on the scene instance with your frame, you can then insert the `Control`s on the `Container` where they belong. That has been the approach in Godot so far... There have been people who has faced similar problems, in fact there was a similar proposal: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/5475 but nothing has come out of that. I'm thinking a dedicated `Control` for this might be better.

Comment: Ah, I see, you can use that to see the internal controls and insert your own in the right place. Jeez, that's somewhere between absolutely horrible (what if you change the frame? or how do you even know what to insert them in if you didn't also write the frame?) and kind of workable.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a simple and automatic way of "eating" the children of a scene in Godot.

However, you could go with 3 different ways to meet your need, which I'm understanding as "showing the same window decorations in every scenes".

---

## Closest to your original question but complicated: moving the content nodes to `LinesContainer`

You could encapsulate all the children of your HexEditor node in a new Control node named "Decorator" ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkGXl.png)), then, in script, move all nodes that are not named "Decorator" in the right container when it enters the tree:

```
func _enter_tree() -> void:
    var container = $Decorator/VBoxContainer/LinesContainer
    for child in get_children():
        if child.name != "Decorator":
            child.reparent(container)
```

(Note that you could also use a [node group](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/groups.html#groups) instead of encapsulating in a new node)

This solution feels a bit hacky to me, and does not display well in the editor (do not try to add `@tool` to run the script in the editor, as this would delete all of the children of the instantiated scene).

---

## Instantiating your content scene inside your `LineContainer`

I feel like going the other way around would be better: instantiating your content scene inside your `LineContainer`.

In the content scenes, do not instantiate the `HexEditor` scene. Put only the node that you want to see inside the `LinesContainer`.

Add a function `change_scene` to your `HexEditor` script, that replaces the child of `LineContainer`:

```
@onready
var container = $VBoxContainer/LinesContainer

func change_scene(scene: Node):
    for child in container.get_children():
        child.queue_free()
    container.add_child(scene)
```

And whenever you need to change the content inside your `LinesContainer`, call this function. For example, in a `content1` scene:

```
var scene = preload("res://content2.tscn")

func on_click():
    get_tree().root.get_node("HexEditor").change_scene(scene.instantiate())
```

You will need to make `HexEditor` the main scene, and, in the `_ready()` function of `HexEditor`, call the `change_scene()` function with your first content scene.

---

## Simplest solution: Header bar scene + theme

However, if you only need the header bar, the simplest way would be to add a scene `HeaderBar` (containing the label "Hex Editor", the close button, and the separator line) as a child of all your content scenes.

In addition, if you also want the same background color for your content scenes, you can use a [`PanelContainer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_panelcontainer.html) as the root of your content scenes and customize their [`StyleBox`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_stylebox.html) by [creating a theme](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/ui/gui_using_theme_editor.html) and adding it as your project theme.

Comment: The comment I wrote above is for exactly this kind of response, no offense. #1 duplicates the insertion code in every child, read up on DRY if you need to know why that is undesirable. #2 prevents me from using different editors with the same frame (I want a hex editor, an asm editor and a C editor, for example, each with their own sub-controls). #3 ignores all other window functions, like minimizing, moving, resizing, etc.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but #1 does not duplicate the insertion code in every child, you only need to add it to the HexEditor script

Comment: `_enter_tree` triggers when a node enter the scene tree, and the event you want here is when a child enters the tree, so the code has to be in the child.